# Python: Using a variable when creating an RTF file

Tags: python, rtf

I am trying to automate creating an RTF file using python with variables. I am able to create it using the code below but I can't figure out how to use the variable "name" in the file.write command.

I tried reading this http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html but can't find anything that would help. Hope somebody can point me to the right direction. Thanks!

```
test = 'file.rtf'
name = "Chris"
file = open(test,'w')
file.write("""{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0
{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}
\\b Name: "%s" % (name,) \\b0\line
}""")
file.close()
```

Comment: Look for "python string interpolation".

Comment: I am familiar with string interpolation but when I use any of those options, it is getting ignored because of the """ . So for the code above, the RTF will contain.

Name: "%s" % (name,)

instead of Name: Chris

Comment: I supose you're using Python 2? in this case add the [tag:python-2.7] tag.

Comment: You should not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "%" add the variable as a string, eg:

```
test = 'file.rtf'
name = "Chris"
file = open(test,'w')
file.write("""{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0
{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}
\\b Name: """ + str(name) + """ \\b0\line
}""")
file.close()
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: @ChrisEvangelio Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center. You should not leave such comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how `%` works -- use it outside of string literals, not inside. So don't use this:

```
"""{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0
{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}
\\b Name: "%s" % (name,) \\b0\line
}"""
```

(because the `% (name,)` part is still *inside* the string literal)

Instead use this:

```
"""{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0
{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}
\\b Name: %s \\b0\line
}""" % (name,)
```

Note that the `% (name,)` is outside of the literal (and the code highlighter correctly identifies that, it's colored black)

<sub>(side note. Using raw string would avoid having to double-escape the backslashes)</sub>